# Can't construct Dictionary for JSON request

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to construct Dictionary with necessary params to send JSON POST request to the server side.

```
let params: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "someRootKey": [
            "someKey": [
                "someKey": someClass.someProperty,
                "someKey": someClass.someProperty,
                "someKey": someClass.someProperty
            ],

            "someKey": someClass.someProperty,
            "someKey": someClass.someProperty,
            "someKey": someClass.someProperty,
            "someKey": someClass.someProperty,
            "someKey": someClass.someProperty,
            "someKey": "someString"
        ]
    ]
```

All values are Strings. However I do get an errors. First one: **[String: AnyObject] is not convertible to [String: AnyObject]**. And second one (near last element in Dictionary): **'_' is not convertible to StringLiteralConvertible**. If I omit type declaration for **params** constant there will be another error: **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**. Can somebody explain what's wrong here?

Comment: You can try with :" someKey": someClass.someProperty as! String

Comment: Well, those are some not helpful error messages you get there - luckily just placing a `!` after every `someProperty` fixes it. You have to unwrap all the Optionals. And you can remove the type declaration in the first line as well after that.

Comment: Could it be that there is a syntax error somewhere before that part in your code? If `someClass.someProperty` is a non-optional string, your code should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a request with a JSON in the body, by constructing it in the form of a string, i.e.:

```
let bodyData = "{\"name\": \"\(self.student_name)\"}"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```